# Proving using the squeezing theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, infinity

The question is :

[image]

I am not sure how i should make the function bigger and smaller in order to find the right limit for it.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you tried using the bound that $0 \le g(x) < 1$?

Comment: I did, and i still can't find it..

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

The key idea is that $|g(x)| < 1$, so it should not contribute to the order neither in the numerator nor in the denominator.